# Mongodb Match against

Tags: mongodb, match, sql-like, rank

In mysql I have a sql look like this

```
SELECT *, match(name) against('abc' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score ......
```

Now I am using mongodb instead of mysql , and in my collection I want to find documents where name or categorie like specific characters and rank its as score

Comment: Hi Yur Gasparyan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry to say that your question isn't a good one here; this site is for asking about specific questions with programming you're _doing_ - it is _not_ for broad questions about how to even start doing the programming. I think you need to find another site with a suitable MongoDB tutorial, and learn from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a "index"

```
db.articulos.createIndex(
  {  
    prodcuto: "text",
    descripcion: "text",
    color: "text"
   }
)
```

the search command look like this:

```
db.articulos.find({ $text: { $search: "Olla Negra 20cm azul"}})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/